# Is there an opensource package/tool for starting/killling/monitoring a remote process through ssh/tcp sockets?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to write an application that can run as a client and a server, with the client and the server talking via ssh/sockets. When the client sends a request to the server, the server should start some child process based on the request from the client, and notify the client if this child process dies.

Instead of starting from scratch, I was wondering if there is any opensource application that already does this.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents, since you are already using ssh for remote connection. With a dedicated application user, do `ssh -i ~/key.file user@remove_server "/path/to/application stop"` or call systemd unit to do it. `ssh -i ~/key.file user@remove_server "systemctl stop application"` where inside the systemd unit file is User=dedicated user

Allow me to expand.

1. SSH allows for remote communication over a secure shell, which is great because the application traffic is encrypted.
2. Using a dedicated application user allows for restriction of what the application user can do. Start and stopping a service is a great way to handle resource and process isolation
3. Using /etc/init.d files are poor idea, because these typically require root privledges to access or run. Where systemD unit files can have a User= which would allow start/stop of the application and also, again, point 2.
4. This discussion revolves around the idea of a "startup" script. For examples, boot up any server and read some bash scripts in /etc/init.d/. They are not the application, but instead small bash code that will start and stop the application in a way that you desire, the same way, everytime.

Hope this helps.